# How do I reverse a list using while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, reverse

Input list: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Output: `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

I know how to do it with for loop, but my assignment is to do it with while loop; which I have no idea to do. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def while_version(items):
   a = 0

 b = len(items)

 r_list = []

  while (a!=b):

        items[a:a] = r_list[(-a)-1]

        a+=1
   return items
```

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct, this is important in Python. It looks like the `return items` is indented, so it will happen the first time through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to make the while loop act like a for loop.

```
firstList = [1,2,3]
secondList=[]

counter = len(firstList)-1

while counter >= 0:
    secondList.append(firstList[counter])
    counter -= 1
```

Comment: No problem, any time!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be:

```
def while_version(items):
    new_list = []
    while items:  # i.e. until it's an empty list
        new_list.append(items.pop(-1))
    return new_list
```

This will reverse the list:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = while_version(l)
>>> l2
[3, 2, 1]
```

Note, however, that it also empties the original list:

```
>>> l1
[]
```

To avoid this, call e.g. `l2 = while_version(l1[:])`.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial answer

Given

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

then

```
a[::-1]
```

returns

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

In your code:

- You use r_list[(-a)+1], buy you have never assigned r_list any value (just "r_list = []")
- I think your are confusing "items" with "r_list". So I think you want to return "r_list" instead of "items" (the input parameter)
- The assignment should be "r_list[a] = items[-a-1]", but that doesn't work. You should use "r_list.append(items[-a-1])"
- The return should be "return r_list"
- "while (a!=b)" should be "while (a < b)" for readeability

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the input! I fixed it earlier, but thanks for clearing up some  stuff for me.